# What is the point of using the 'to_sym' method?

Tags: ruby, methods, symbols

I'm trying to build a rock, paper, scissors game, and while looking at other people's code for a bit, I noticed that some are using 'to_sym'. They have a hash, with a string for a key and an array with two string elements for elements as the key. I've tried to figure out why they would do that, but I'm lost.

Example:

```
WIN_CONDITIONS = { rock: ["lizard", "scissors"],
                   paper: ["rock", "spock"],
                   scissors: ["paper", "lizard"],
                   lizard: ["paper", "spock"],
                   spock: ["scissors", "rock"]
                  }

def win?(first, second)
  WIN_CONDITIONS[first.to_sym].include?(second)
end
```

Comment: As a sort of followup, why would someone want to use a symbol? Why not just use a string? Generally, when you need something 'string like' but it should be part of the CODE, instead of the DATA, a symbol is preferred. They are immutable (can't change them, this protects you in many ways), there is only one copy of it in memory (unlike strings, which are created and thrown away), and they make really good identifiers in general.

Comment: Thank you for the added info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with a string for a key

Here's where you're wrong. Those are symbols. Therefore, you need the `.to_sym`, if you hope to lookup the value correctly.

Comment: So where it says [first.to_sym].include?(second), what is the 'first', the symbol key and the 'second' is the array itself? I apologize, I'm very new to programming and I'm shaky on this stuff.

Comment: @Felicia `WIN_CONDITIONS[first.to_sym]` get you an array of winning moves. Then you call `include?` on that array to see if this particular move (`second`) is there.

Comment: Thank you @Sergio that helps a lot.